# OWL; Property chaining

Tags: owl, protege, description-logic, manchester-syntax

I have OWL ontology without individuals. Given two classes

```
Cs
```

and

```
Cd
```

How will the query look like an what type of reasoners can be used to find all the property chains such that:

```
(Cs subClassOf PropertyP exactly 1 Cd)
```

Where Cs is the domain of PropertyP and Cd is its range.
Chain means that this inference must be **transitive**, i.e. if

```
(Cs subClassOf PropertyP1 exactly one Ctemp) and (Ctemp subClassOf PropertyP2 exactly one Cd)
```

then, {PropertyP1, PropertyP2} must be considered a property chain between Cs and Cd.

Please note that I'm **not talking about property chain such that one in OWL2**, because in the case of OWL2, I have to define this chain previously, while in my case I cannot do so.

Comment: No, you can't.  The DL Query pane lets you enter a *class* epxression can get back superclasses and subclasses of that class, and individuals belonging to it.  You can't use the DL Query pane to get a list of properties.

Comment: Then you mean that this task cannot be completed using a reasoner & I have to enjoy some coding to perform it?

Comment: A reasoner might be able to help you with this, but reasoners may be able to do more than what you can do in the DL Query pane.

Comment: Thanks. You say "_but reasoners may be able to do **more** than what you can do in the DL Query pane_". That seems interesting for me, I have two points please: 1-) How can this "**MORE**" be done in a way other than DL-Query pane? I only know this way (DL_Query) to ask the reasoner for some inferences. 2-) Can my question above be answered using reasoner (disregarding that DL_Query pane can't be used)? 3-) Please put your comments as answers in order to tick it as solution. Thanks

Comment: For instance, Pellet's command line tools come bundled with Jena, and you can run SPARQL queries against an ontology.  Thus you could query `select ?p where { <x> ?p <y> }` and get a list of properties relating x and y.  You can't do that with the DL query pane. That means working outside of Protege, though.  I'm not sure whether or not the query above could be answered or not;  it would depend on the particular reasoner (but you haven't mentioned a particular one that you want to use).  I haven't posted any of these as answers yet, because these aren't really answers to the question as

Comment: it's written yet.  If you're willing to accept answers that involve using reasoners outside of Protege, could you update the question to indicate that?  Then I might be able to post an answer.